# Nginx server laravel route directory 404 error on Windows

Tags: windows, laravel, nginx, http-status-code-404

I'm getting a 404 every time I try to open a page other than the welcome page. I've read all the posts here on how to fix the problem, but none of the solutions worked for me.
I'm on Windows 10 and use WPN-XM for the Nginx server.
My laravel project is installed in C:/server/www/myapp

My configuration looks as follows:

```
server {
    listen          127.0.0.1:80;
    server_name     localhost;
    root            www;
    index           index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files      $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   php_pool;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #fastcgi_param  PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS 1000;
        #fastcgi_param  PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN 100;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR $http_x_real_ip;
        # mitigate namespace conflict, see httpoxy.org
        fastcgi_param  HTTP_PROXY "";
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
```

I tried replacing root www with "C:/server/www/myapp/public" and a couple of other options.
I used try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args instead of try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: root should be your full path and listen should be just 80  afaik. :)

Comment: Try a different server stack, [WinNMP](https://winnmp.wtriple.com) and read their tutorial [Create a new LARAVEL Project](https://winnmp.wtriple.com/howtoFrameworks#Create-a-new-LARAVEL-Project)